# Wrong results with Ego-motion estimation

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

Task: estimate the self-motion (pitch, yaw and row angles) of a mono-camera while the car is driving.

Tools (openCV, codes below): `ORB` feature detector -> `BFMatcher` -> `findEssentialMat` -> `decomposeEssentialMat`

General process: I input the current & previous frame, detect the ORB features respectively, match them (sorted by score). Then use the `findEssentialMat` to estimate the essential matrix, and decompose the rotation matrix `R` into Euler angles.

Problem: time to time there would be "outlier" estimates, e.g. two frames with really little difference gave results like `[-12.2,-49.1,14.0]` (in degrees, original [frame1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDDNK.png) and [frame2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKQDh.png)). However, in most of the frames, it works pretty fine.

Debug tries:

- I plot out the image with matched features, there are no visible wrong matches (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGwAR.png)).
- Since the `FindEssentialMat` gave two possible answers, I chose the better one with some criteria.
- I manually take out the wrong frames (by sanpshots) and run estimation independently, there's no problem!!! But as I directly estimate the original frames in debug mode, still wrong (T.T really confused here).

Here are some example codes:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def isRotMat(R):
    Rt = np.transpose(R)
    shouldBeIdentity = np.dot(Rt, R)
    I = np.identity(3, dtype=R.dtype)
    n = np.linalg.norm(I - shouldBeIdentity)
    return n < 1e-6
def rotMat2EulAng(R):
    assert (isRotMat(R))
    assert (R[2, 0] != 1)
    y = -math.asin(R[2, 0])
    y = min(abs(y), abs(math.pi + y))

    x = math.atan2(R[2, 1] / math.cos(y), R[2, 2] / math.cos(y))
    z = math.atan2(R[1, 0] / math.cos(y), R[0, 0] / math.cos(y))
    x = math.degrees(x)
    y = math.degrees(y)
    z = math.degrees(z)
    return np.array([x, y, z])

# select more reasonable answer
def sel_ang(ang1, ang2, R1, R2):
    if np.sum(abs(ang2)) > np.sum(abs(ang1)):
        ang = ang1
        R = R1
    else:
        ang = ang2
        R = R2
    return ang, R

# Initialize
orb = cv.ORB_create()
bf = cv.BFMatcher()
img_train = frame1
img_query = frame2
foc_len = 1000    # not important
# exlude moving cars (preliminary method)
crop = 0.5
img_train = img_train[0:int(crop*frame1.shape[0]), 0:frame1.shape[1]]
img_query = img_query[0:int(crop*frame2.shape[0]), 0:frame2.shape[1]]

# ORB feature detection
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img_train, None)  # query
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img_query, None)  # train

# Feature matching, sorted
matches = bf.match(des2, des1)
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)[:12]
img_out = cv.drawMatches(img_query, kp2, img_train, kp1, matches, None,
                           flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

# etract point coordinates, and estimate the Essential matrix
kpts1 = np.array([kp1[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches], dtype=np.int)
kpts2 = np.array([kp2[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches], dtype=np.int)
essMat, ret = cv.findEssentialMat(kpts1, kpts2, focal=foc_len)  # focal length to be revised

# decompose into two possible R matrix,
# and select a more reasonable one
R1, R2, _ = cv.decomposeEssentialMat(essMat)
rotAngs1 = rotMat2EulAng(R1)
rotAngs2 = rotMat2EulAng(R2)
rotAngs, RMat = sel_ang(rotAngs1, rotAngs2, R1, R2)

# output
img_out = cv.cvtColor(img_out, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(img_out), plt.show()
```

I hope you could provide some insights. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just an idea: there is an optional parameter for `cv.findEssentialMat` called mask. It shows how many points were used for the calculation of the Essential Matrix. You could check if always all of your 12 points are used for the final Essential matrix you are decomposing later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did check this parameter. There were 8 pnts counted, and the minimum amount for this function is 5 pnts. So I guess that would not be the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Grillteller. In light of your suggestions about the pnts amount,  I increase the amount up to 20 pnts, and it has helped a lot! No outliers anymore (still inaccurate sometimes, but that's another problem).The minimum amount is 8 so I thought I just need to satisfy this, but it turns out that the more the better, because it's an optimization problem after all :)